# How do I know the probability for me to be ranked in the 2nd place or last 2nd place?

Tags: probability, statistics

I took a course with other 9 students. After the final exam, professor reported statistical result of scores to us:
1. The range of score: 46~98;
2. The average of score: 73.3;
3  The SD of score: 14.3;
I got 81, without any further information, how do I know the probabilities for me to be ranked in the 2nd place or the last 2nd place?

Comment: You don't know them, and can't know them unless you assume a particular probability model for the scores.

Answer (score 2):

The chance of second to last is zero.  If you were second to last, the last was $46$.  There were a total of $660$ points scored.  The average of other seven is then $660-81-46\approx 76$ and at least one more is below your score.  You cannot use the same reasoning for second place as the average of the six other than you, top, and bottom is $72.5$  You can create a distribution to give the proper standard deviation as well while keeping your $81$ in second place.  $46,65,65,65,80,80,80,81,98$ has the proper average and a standard deviation of $14.81$, while $46,72,72,72,73,73,73,81,98$ has a standard deviation of $13.32$